# Filter commerce orders by the user that updates there state

Tags: views, commerce

If a user updates the state of several orders to completed.

I want to then use views to filter all orders that had there state marked completed by that user.

Is this possible i have tried but failed?

I would also like to filter by the order state updated date.

Comment: Is state a field in the order or you are referring to order status ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by creating a view based on commerce order revisions. The revision uid and state are available.